# Prefab loaded by Resources.Load can not be rendered on scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a `Prefab` and I load it in the `Awake` function with the following code:

```
GameObject bulletPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Enemy/Bullet");
bulletPrefab.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

The problem is that the `bulletPrefab` is not gonna show in the game scene. Its `activeSelf` property is `true` but its `activeInHierarchy` property is `false`. Does anyone know why it is like this and how to make the `bulletprefab` show in the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not modify a prefab. You tried to modify it when you did `bulletPrefab.transform.position = ...`

The `bulletPrefab` is a loaded GameObject which is only stored in the memory. To see it, you have to instantiate it with the Instantiate function. You seem to have done this in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700810/trail-renderer-does-not-behave-correctly) but for some reason decided to remove that critical part in this question.

---

Looking at your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700810/trail-renderer-does-not-behave-correctly), it seems like your issue is shooting the prefab. You don't shoot the prefab by setting the bullet's position to another position in **one** frame. You can use a coroutine and do that over multiple frames or you can use `Rigidbody` for this. I suggest using `Rigidbody` because that's the kind of stuff it is made for.

Makes sure that `Rigidbody` is attached to the prefab you want to load. Load the prefab, instantiate it then get the `Rigidbody` attached to it. Move the bullet to the front of the player + camera then use `Rigidbody.velocity` or `Rigidbody.AddForce` to shoot the bullet to the `CameraTransform.forward` direction so that *the bullet will travel to the direction the camera is facing*.

See below for example of loading and shooting a bullet prefab when space key is pressed.

```
GameObject bulletPrefab;
Transform cameraTransform;
public float bulletSpeed = 300;

private void Start()
{
    //Load Prefab
    bulletPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Enemy/Bullet");

    //Get camera transform
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
}

void Update()
{
    //Shoot bullet when space key is pressed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        shootBullet();
    }
}

void shootBullet()
{
    //Instantiate prefab
    GameObject tempObj = Instantiate(bulletPrefab) as GameObject;

    //Set position of the bullet in front of the player
    tempObj.transform.position = transform.position + cameraTransform.forward;

    //Get the Rigidbody that is attached to that instantiated bullet
    Rigidbody projectile = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    //Shoot the Bullet 
    projectile.velocity = cameraTransform.forward * bulletSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation which is exactly what I have been looking for. I will try your solution, then back to tell you the result.

Comment: Np. Notice that `transform.position + cameraTransform.forward` is used. This assumes that this script is attached to the player or the place you want the bullet to shoot from. That's what `transform.position` is used for.

Comment: Still no luck. I tried the above code it gives me the similar unwanted trail. In both approaches, the unwanted trail stops showing after showing up several times.

Comment: The unwanted trail is actually a line between the start position of the bullet and the bullet  prefab. The real trail is a moving line segment. I can not figure out what leads this behaviour.

Comment: What is the bullet object? What type of object? can you show video that describes what you mean by trail?

Comment: Finally I got this issue fixed. After thinking about all the possible steps in the procedure, I found the problem is caused by how I instantiated the bulletprefab. I should choose "Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)" rather than "Instantiate(Object original)". The first version of instantiate creates the bullet in the given position. The second instantiate creates the bullet where the bullet prefab located so relocate the prefab will cause rendering a trail. If its the first case, I do not need to relocate the bullet.

Comment: You can set the initial point of the bullet in the Instantiate function or you can do that after instantiating  it like I did in the second line in the `shootBullet` function. `tempObj.transform.position = transform.position + cameraTransform.forward`. The code in this answer is made to make the object appear regalress of where the camera is facing but if you already have a static location you want the object to appear, you just replace `tempObj.transform.position = transform.position + cameraTransform.forward` with `tempObj.transform.position = yourLocation`,

Comment: But doing it with `Instantiate(bulletPrefab,yourLocation,yourRot)` will also work too.

Comment: You are welcome. If any these answered answered your question don't forget to accept one.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have accepted this answer much earlier.

Comment: No problem at all